# Is there a central anti-patent database for openly developed and abandoned inventions?

Tags: defensive-publications, public-domain

Sites like [HalfBakery](http://halfbakery.com) and [this shared Google Doc](http://goo.gl/alj3D) act as open repositories for potentially patentable inventions. In effect, these sites act as anti-patent databases because the inventions are never pursued, but are available as prior art in the public domain. Is there currently a site or service that aggregates all of these different open repositories into one location?

Answer (score 2):

[Defensivepublications.org](http://defensivepublications.org/) has done some work in this direction, but there is no centralized database that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of a centralized database.  Yet another resource is [IP.com](http://www.ip.com).  They have have a defensive publication service.  You have to pay to publish there, but you'll have the benefit of a more trustworthy documentation system.

Answer (score 0):

Research Disclosure have been offering this kind of defensive publication service for a long time.

Research Disclosure is included in the PCT minimum documentation list, the major patent authorities are required to search the archive when examining patent applications.

It's a paid service but if you're looking to create an effective block against future patents it's a good solution.

2 min intro to defensive publication strategy :: [vimeo.com/questel/defensivepublication](http://vimeo.com/questel/defensivepublication)

website :: [researchdisclosure.com](http://www.researchdisclosure.com/)

Comment: Note that I believe Defensivepublications.org publishes their materials into the RD database, so there may be a two-birds, one-stone solution there.